# Let U be Maximal among non-principal ideals of R. (Question regarding phrasing)

Tags: ring-theory, predicate-logic

With regard the above statement, is the author trying to say:

(1):$ $ $\forall z \lhd R(z$ is non-principal $\land$ $U\subseteq z$ $\land$ $U\neq R$ $\Rightarrow U=z$ $ \lor$ $ z=R )$

or

(2): Suppose U is non-principal. Then $ $ $\forall z \lhd R(z$ is non-principal $\land$ $U\subseteq z$ $\land$ $U\neq R$ $\Rightarrow U=z$ $ \lor$ $ z=R )$

If it is the first case, then there could be a possibility that a ring exists with a principal ideal - $U=(k)$ - such that all non-principal ideals are a strict subset of it. In which case 1 still holds since the premise is always false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should interpret it as "$U$ is a non-principal ideal with the property that there does not exist a non-principal ideal of $R$ strictly containing $U$."

---

If I were forced to <s>encode</s> encrypt what you said in in logical notation, I would write what those words say:

$U \text{ is non-principal }\wedge(\not\exists z\lhd R((z\text{ non-principal })\wedge (z\supsetneq U)))$

which would be equivalent, of course, to

$U \text{ is non-principal }\wedge(\forall z\lhd R((z\supsetneq U)\implies z\text{ is principal}))$

---

Also, you are probably assuming $R$ has identity, so it would never be the case that $R=z$, right? I think perhaps you are being confused by a quirk of the definition often given for maximal ideals.

By definition, a maximal ideal is

$M \text{ is a proper ideal }\wedge(\forall z\lhd R((z\text{ is a proper ideal })\wedge(z\supseteq M)\implies z=M))$

which can be restated as

$M \text{ is a proper ideal }\wedge(\forall z\lhd R((z\supseteq M)\implies (z=M)\vee (z=R)))$

Comment: Yes. So you assume that U is non-principal?

Comment: @JhonDoe Yes, because "among non-principal ideals" means it is a member of the set of non-prinicipal ideals.

Comment: i think that for the general definition of a maximal ideal, you dont need the assumption that M is non-principal. i.e 3Z in Z

Comment: @JhonDoe Cut and paste error, of course.